# Example of a normal, $T_0$ space which is not Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

The definition of "normal" I use in this question is the same as on Wikipedia and as in Munkres' "Topology": any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by disjoint neighbourhoods. Similarly, T${}_1$ means any two distinct points can be separated by neighbourhoods, and T${}_0$ means any two distinct points are topologically distinguishable.

Now, it's easy to see that a normal T${}_1$ space is Hausdorff (since singletons are closed, hence normalcy on singletons reduces to Hausdorffness). I'm curious if that's the weakest additional separation axiom needed in order to guarantee Hausdorfness, or if we can go any further.

Based on my own fiddling around trying to prove it, I would guess that normal + T${}_0$ does *not* imply Hausdorff, but I haven't looked for a counterexample yet. Are there any normal T${}_0$, non-Hausdorff counterexamples that would disprove this claim?

Comment: I'm not sure if you correctly stated what $T_1$ means. $T_0$ means that for any $x$ and $y$, there is an open $U$ that contains exactly one of $x$ and $y$. $T_1$ means that for any $x$ and $y$, there is an open $U$ with $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$. $T_2$ means that for any $x$ and $y$, there exist disjoint open $U$ and $V$ with $x\in U$ and $y\in V$. A space is defined to be Hausdorff iff it is $T_2$. At least, these are the definitions from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom See also the Wikipedia page about $T_1$ spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space

Comment: I was trying to state them briskly, but thanks for adding more detail :) your definitions are precisely what I meant.

Comment: I wasn't sure if my comment was necessary or not, so I'm glad you didn't mind.

Comment: Overpowered answer: The Zariski topology on any algebraically closed field in $n$ indeterminates satisfies this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=\{0,1\}$, and let $\mathcal{T}=\left\{\emptyset,\{0\},X\right\}$. Then $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a $T_0$ topological space.

Let $A$ and $B$ be closed sets with $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Then it must be the case that either $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$. In the former case, let $U=\emptyset$ and let $V=X$. In the latter case let $U=X$ and let $V=\emptyset$. It follows that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets with $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$.

Finally, $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is not $T_1$, since there is no open $U$ with $1\in U$ and $0\notin U$.

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate the answer, tho some part of me is still philosophically unsatisfied because there's really only one "closed" set (which isn't also open) in this space, namely {1}, and so it feels kind of "vacuously" normal. I suppose though that any such small counterexample will fail to enlighten on why T0'ness isn't enough to guarantee Hausdorffness, and must simply be accepted as a "true statement" devoid of any further elucidation

Comment: @user3002473 You can get examples with lots of closed sets by taking the disjoint union of many copies of the example in this answer.  Equivalently, take the product of the space in this answer with an arbitrary discrete space. But those examples might not help your philosophical part.